# How to add a wifi connection if I'm not within range

Tags: networking, wireless, wpa-supplicant, nmcli

I'm refurbishing laptops (Ubuntu 20.04) to hand out to kids as part of combating digital exclusion during COVID-19. Obviously I don't want to give them sudo access, however, I can't enter their houses to get onto WiFi.

How do I add a new connection when I set the laptop up (they can give me their SSID / passwords)?

I've tried

```
nmcli d wifi connect WiFi-SSID password 12345678
```

but that fails since the wifi isn't in range. I've tried

```
nmcli connection add type wifi ssid WIFI-SSID password 12345678
```

but that's throwing an `invalid <setting>.<property> 'password'`

Not sure where to go next...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

read `man nm-settings`

a general example is

```
nmcli connection add type wifi con-name outofrange ssid HUAWEI 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt WPA-PSK 802-11-wireless-security.psk xxxxxxxx
```

the error in your question `<setting>.<property>` for example in above command,

`<setting> 802-11-wireless-security <property> key-mgmt`
`<setting> 802-11-wireless-security <property> psk`

Based on your OutOfRange connection settings change the above values..

Answer (score 1):

You have to set all of options below in that order:

```
nmcli connection modify <ssid> wifi-sec.auth-alg open wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk <password>
```

Comment: `man nm-settings-nmcli`